# How to call an OAuthV2 API from other OAuthV2 API by passing token in Authentication Headers

Tags: oauth-2.0

Our team works on the following applications:

- UIApp              --> Gets OAuthV2 token
- Api1, Api2, Api3   --> Supports OAuthV2, Get user details from OAuthv2 token to get user related data

We have a scenario where UIApp calls Api1 by passing OAuthV2 token (ex. Token1). Now internally Api1 calls Api2 to fetch some data. My question is:

1. Can I pass the same token (Token1) received by Api1 to Api2?
2. OR Do we need to get a new token in Api1 so that we can pass it to Api2 while calling it? In case if this is true, Token1 contains user claims. How can we still generate a token which will be accepted by Api2 and stil contains user infromation

Answer (score 0):

Technically, bearer tokens can be forwarded from api1 to api2 - OAuth supports this nicely.

However, this raises wider questions around scoping, hosting security and what things are allowed to call each other architecturally. Often it makes sense to have some rules around this.

I tend to use a rule that a UI only calls an API tailored to the UI's requirements - and this 'consumer' API can only call core APIs:
https://authguidance.com/2019/03/24/api-platform-design/

Getting a second token may not be recommended and adds complexity around areas like performance and expiry.

Also, to get a token containing a user id means that the user may need to consent to this - and you can't manage that if you are getting a new token invisibly.